# SAS: Merging two datasets

Tags: merge, sas

I am new to stackoverflow and hope someone can help with SAS question I have.
I have two SAS datasets with the following columns:

File 1(example):

```
 id, a1, b1, var1,var2   
 1,50,20,a,1    
 1,40,15,b,2  
 1,30,25,c,3    
 1,23,17,d,4    
 2,45,26,e,5    
 2,34,14,f,6    
 2,32,18,g,7    
 3,67,32,h,8    
 3,58,27,j,9    
 3,33,16,k,10   
 4,42,35,l,11    
 4,26,16,m,12    
 4,36,19,n,13    
 ...
```

File 2(example):

```
 id, x1,x2,y1,y2  
 1,23,50,15,25  
 2,32,45,14,26  
 3,33,67,16,32  
 4,26,42,16,35  
 ...
```

I need to merge these two files and perform the following condition on File 1:

```
 if x1<=a1<=x2 and y1<=b1<=y2
```

If condition is satisfied then

1. output all columns from File 1 and File 2,
2. rename unique_id from File 2 to unique_id_2 and
3. create new File 3 that will have the following structure:

File 3(results):

```
 id, id_2, a1,b1,var1,var2
```

The resulting file will have all observations that satisfy condition classified by unique_id, unique_id_2 and all columns from the File 1 and File 2. Resulting file File 3 will have many more observations than File 1 since various observations from various unique_id from File 1 can satisfy condition that is contained in File 2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

** Additional comment ***
While waiting for reply I tried this code which I think works(I need to check it):

```
data File3;  
set File2(rename=(id=id_2));
do i=1 to nobs;  
set File1 point=i nobs=nobs;  
if x1<=a1<=x2 and y1<=b1<=y2 then output;  
end;  
run;
```

Comment: What output do you want (show explicitly for one or two ids) ? What code have you tried ? File1 does not have unique id values (over all rows), there are repeats.  Not a problem, but the name `unique_id` is misleading.

Comment: I have updated the post (removing unique) with the code I tried. I think it works but need to double check. Basically I want to output all observations from File1 that satisfy condition and condition is based in File2. So for id=1 in File2 I want to find all observations in File1 and output them to File3. THe sam eprocess is then repeated for all IDs in File 2.  IDs in File1 and File2 are the same, the only difference is that File 1 have more observations within every ID. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach, due to File2 really having unique id values would be

```
data want;
  merge file2 file1;
  by id;
  * subsetting if, any thing that passes through is output;
  if x1<=a1<=x2 and y1<=b1<=y2;
run;
```

Since merge is by `id` and id is common to both tables, you don't need `unique_id_2`.

However, if you are joining every row of `file1` to `file2` regardless of `id`, I would recommend `Proc SQL` cross join.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    file1.unique_id, file2.unique_id as unique_id_2
  , file2.x1, file1.a1, file2.x2
  , file2.y1, file1.b1, file2.y2
  from file1
  cross join file2
  where x1<=a1<=x2 and y1<=b1<=y2 
  ;
```